# Django model generating easily editable response according to BooleanField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing web page where people can add their clients, something like adress book, where they can check if the client which they add wants option nr 1 or nr 2 or both of them and i want django to generate link if option 1 or two or both of them are checked, that consists of URL adress PLUS author's "subid". Here's the tricky part: URL adress(the first part of link that i want django to generate) needs to be easily changeable, preferably in django-admin page.

**Example:**

Mark, whose subid is cli30 added a client who wants option 1 and 2 so i want to save in database in addition to clients personal information two links : option1/abc_cli30 (option1/abc_ + cli30) AND option2/abc_cli30 (option2/abc_ + cli30). Then, when someone else with "subid" cli22 added another client who wants only option 1, so I need to generate only option1/abc_cli22. Then after a for example a month, if someone adds a new client, i want django to generate opt1.com/cli30.

Here are relevant part my of models.py:

```
class Clients(links):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default=" ")  #personal info about client
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=False, default=" ")
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default=" ")
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    option1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)  #checkbox for option1
    option2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)  #chockbox for option2
    who_added = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)  # here is the author who added client
    link_opt1= models.OneToOneField(links)
    link_opt2 = models.OneToOneField(links)

class Links(models.Model):
    link_opt1= models.CharField(option1.com)   # here are the first parts of links i need to generate
    link_opt2= models.CharField(option2.com)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True'
```

As you can see I tried already with making an abstract class and Client class would inherit then from this class but then links in Links class wouldn't be easily changeable.

Then i tried with OneToOne relationship and saving final links with "subid" in Client class in views.py but I couldn't make it in right way. Also considered making Queryset in admin page, which would filter all the objects with option 1 or option 2 checked and then according to current link in Links class and author who added generate proper link, which seemed like the best option to choose but this was also the hardest to do.

Could you please help me write it? Any piece of advice would be very helpful!

Comment: This is not a question - this is a "do my job" request.

Comment: No, I don't want anybody to "do my job", I only need help in choosing the best way i should do it, do i need to try with queryset, abstract class or something else.